# Why calling a function like this works in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have the following Scala code snippet:

```
type Set = Int => Boolean

def contains(s: Set, element:Int): Boolean = s(element)

def singletonSet(element: Int): Set = Set(element)

val oneElementSet = singletonSet(5)

contains(oneElementSet, 5) // true
contains(oneElementSet, 6) // false
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around what this does: Set(element). Looks like it'll substitute element in place of an Int argument, to produce this: 5 => Boolean. There is no comparison anywhere, so why does oneElementSet(5) returns true, and oneElementSet(6) returns false?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you check the full package where the `Set` returned by `singletonSet` is defined? I think you're just using the normal `Set` under `scala.collection.immutable`, try to set `type Set = Int => Int`, if your code still works then you are not really using the `Set` you defined but the one under `scala.collection.immutable`.

Comment: This looks like the coursera FunProg. I'd use a different name for the Set type to avoid collisions with `scala.collection.immutable.Set`  Do something like: `type MySet = Int => Boolean`  and it should *not* work. The impl of singleton set is wrong from an exercise perspective. Hint: `singletonSet` should be implemented with the function definition at hand: `Int => Boolean`

Comment: This is indeed from 'Functional Programming in Scala' course on Coursera. Thanks for the tip ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala has separate namespaces for types and values. Your type alias defines what `Set` is in the type namespace, but in the definition of `singletonSet` `Set` comes from the value namespace, in fact it is the companion object [`scala.collection.immutable.Set`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Set%24). `Set(element)` invokes the `apply` method of the companion object, which returns a `scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]`, which turns out to be a subtype of `Int => Boolean` and therefore is a `Set` (your type alias) as well.

Comment: Yes, that was it. `Set(element)` creates an instance of `scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]`. Thanks a lot everyone for helping me out!